# How can I combine multiple graphs into a single in R?

Tags: r, graph

I wrote this code :

```
duom=read.delim("clipboard",header=TRUE) 
dim(duom)
duom
Duom=ts(duom,start=2000,freq=4)


dLT=diff(Duom[,3])
dLT
plot(dLT)
abline(0,0)
dLT
LT<-decompose(dLT)$trend
plot(decompose(dLT)$trend)
abline(0,0)


dLV=diff(Duom[,2])
dLV
plot(dLV)
abline(0,0)
dLV
LV<-decompose(dLV)$trend
plot(decompose(dLV)$trend)
abline(0,0)


dEE=diff(Duom[,1])
dEE
plot(dEE)
abline(0,0)
dEE
EE<-decompose(dEE)$trend
plot(decompose(dEE)$trend)
abline(0,0)
```

so I get three different graphs of LT,LV and EE. I want to combine them into a single image (colours of curves should be different), how can I do that ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your example, but here's an example of how to plot lines of different colors on the same plot `x <- replicate(3, rnorm(5)); plot(x[,1], type = "l"); lapply(2:3, function(y) lines(x[,y], col = y))`  Please provide a few lines of your data so that we can show how to do it with your code.

Comment: Use `plot(...)` for the first plot then use lines(..., col=someColor) for the remaining data. For time series you can get the `x` values via `time(serie)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simulated data:

```
data = ts(replicate(3, cumsum(rnorm(1000))), freq = 4, start = 2000)
dec = decompose(data)
ylim = range(dec$trend, na.rm = TRUE)

plot(dec$trend[, 1], ylim = ylim)
for(i in 2:ncol(dec$trend))
    lines(dec$trend[, i], col = i)

abline(0, 0, col = 'darkgray')
```

Hope it helps!